# Getting Null values for all entries into access database using C#. Why?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2013

I am currently in the progress of creating a database that stores parking information.  Now I am able to successfully connect to the database and add an entry and then add another entry etc.  However when I view the table in Access I don't see anything I entered in each of the records and when I view the table in Visual Studio it shows each record as being Null.

What could I have done wrong?  I am fairly new to not only programming but databases as well.

Below is the the code for my app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace ParkingDatabase
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection DBConnect = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            DBConnect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\bkoso\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParkingDatabase\ParkingDatabase\ParkingData.accdb";
            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
            if (DBConnect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Guest Info]([Guest First Name], [Guest Last Name], [Room Number], [Departure Date], [Return Date], [Vehicle Colour], [Vehicle Make], [Plate Number], [Contact First Name], [Contact Last Name], [Contact Number], [Contact Email], [Tag Number]) Values(@[Guest First Name], @[Guest Last Name], @[Room Number], @[Departure Date], @[Return Date], @[Vehicle Colour], @[Vehicle Make], @[Plate Number], @[Contact First Name], @[Contact Last Name], @[Contact Email], @[Contact Email], @[Tag Number])", DBConnect);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Guest First Name]", txtBxGstFName.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Guest Last Name]", txtBxGstLName.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Room Number]", txtBxRm.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Departure Date]", txtBxDDate.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Return Date]", txtBxRDate.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Vehicle Colour]", txtBxVColour.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Vehicle Make]", txtBxVMake.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Plate Number]", txtBxPlate.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact First Name]", txtBxContactFName.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact Last Name]", txtBxContactLName.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact Number]", txtBxPhone.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact Email]", txtBxEmail.Text);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Tag Number]", txtBxTag.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                DBConnect.Open();
                OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Guest Info]([Guest First Name], [Guest Last Name], [Room Number], [Departure Date], [Return Date], [Vehicle Colour], [Vehicle Make], [Plate Number], [Contact First Name], [Contact Last Name], [Contact Number], [Contact Email], [Tag Number]) Values(@[Guest First Name], @[Guest Last Name], @[Room Number], @[Departure Date], @[Return Date], @[Vehicle Colour], @[Vehicle Make], @[Plate Number], @[Contact First Name], @[Contact Last Name], @[Contact Email], @[Contact Email], @[Tag Number])", DBConnect);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Guest First Name]", txtBxGstFName.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Guest Last Name]", txtBxGstLName.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Room Number]", txtBxRm.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Departure Date]", txtBxDDate.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Return Date]", txtBxRDate.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Vehicle Colour]", txtBxVColour.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Vehicle Make]", txtBxVMake.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Plate Number]", txtBxPlate.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact First Name]", txtBxContactFName.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact Last Name]", txtBxContactLName.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact Number]", txtBxPhone.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact Email]", txtBxEmail.Text);
                com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Tag Number]", txtBxTag.Text);
            }


            if (DBConnect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                //com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
                MessageBox.Show("Guest Information Saved Successfully");
                txtBxGstFName.Text = "";
                txtBxGstLName.Text = "";
                txtBxRm.Text = "";
                txtBxDDate.Text = "";
                txtBxRDate.Text = "";
                txtBxVColour.Text = "";
                txtBxVMake.Text = "";
                txtBxPlate.Text = "";
                txtBxContactFName.Text = "";
                txtBxContactLName.Text = "";
                txtBxPhone.Text = "";
                txtBxEmail.Text = "";
                txtBxTag.Text = "";
        }
    }    

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtBxGstFName.Text = "";
        txtBxGstLName.Text = "";
        txtBxRm.Text = "";
        txtBxDDate.Text = "";
        txtBxRDate.Text = "";
        txtBxVColour.Text = "";
        txtBxVMake.Text = "";
        txtBxPlate.Text = "";
        txtBxContactFName.Text = "";
        txtBxContactLName.Text = "";
        txtBxPhone.Text = "";
        txtBxEmail.Text = "";
        txtBxTag.Text = "";
    }

    private void btnView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSame_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtBoxGuestFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bloodstalker

Comment: where are you getting null?

Comment: You're setting up a few queries, but are you executing any them? For example, `com1.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Why do you have ExecuteNonQuery() commented out? That's the call that will actually execute the query you have set up.

Comment: @JeffFerguson: Agreed, and I don't think `com` is even used, so there's nothing to execute, even if it wasn't commented out...

Comment: I had ExecuteNonQuery() commented out because it was always throwing an exception, but when it was commented out i thought it was working, even though the record that appeared to be created was null for every column in my table.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of problems I can see straight away

1. You create a new connection each time - which is correct - but its state will never be `Open`
2. You initialise `com` as a command but never use it. No parameters are configured
3. You initialise `com1` and `com2` set their parameters, but never execute either of them
4. The line where you actually execute `com` is commented out.

You should initialise `com`, set its parameters, open the connection, and call `ExecuteNonQuery` and ditch all the code where you set up `com1` and `com2` - both are irrelevant and unnecessary.

For example:

```
using (OleDbConnection DBConnect = new OleDbConnection())
{
      DBConnect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\bkoso\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParkingDatabase\ParkingDatabase\ParkingData.accdb";
     using(OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Guest Info]([Guest First Name], [Guest Last Name], [Room Number], [Departure Date], [Return Date], [Vehicle Colour], [Vehicle Make], [Plate Number], [Contact First Name], [Contact Last Name], [Contact Number], [Contact Email], [Tag Number]) Values(@[Guest First Name], @[Guest Last Name], @[Room Number], @[Departure Date], @[Return Date], @[Vehicle Colour], @[Vehicle Make], @[Plate Number], @[Contact First Name], @[Contact Last Name], @[Contact Email], @[Contact Email], @[Tag Number])", DBConnect))
     {
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Guest First Name]", txtBxGstFName.Text);
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Guest Last Name]", txtBxGstLName.Text);
       // .. snip other params .. //
       DBConnect.Open();
       com.ExecuteNonQuery();
       DBConnect.Close();
     }
}
```

As an aside, you should not hard-code the connection string but read it from a config file.

Comment: I've done what you suggested and I'm now getting an exception error which shows as follows: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '@[Guest First Name]'.

Comment: Also I believe I saved the connection string to a config file, but I don't know how to access it.

Answer (score 2):

Your command is set up, but you never execute the query. The execution is what you will need to actually run the query command and save the records in the database. You need to call `com1.ExecuteNonQuery()` or `com2.ExecuteNonQuery()` as appropriate.

You can most likely reduce the method to something like the following:

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection DBConnect = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        DBConnect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\bkoso\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParkingDatabase\ParkingDatabase\ParkingData.accdb";
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Guest Info]([Guest First Name], [Guest Last Name], [Room Number], [Departure Date], [Return Date], [Vehicle Colour], [Vehicle Make], [Plate Number], [Contact First Name], [Contact Last Name], [Contact Number], [Contact Email], [Tag Number]) Values(@[Guest First Name], @[Guest Last Name], @[Room Number], @[Departure Date], @[Return Date], @[Vehicle Colour], @[Vehicle Make], @[Plate Number], @[Contact First Name], @[Contact Last Name], @[Contact Email], @[Contact Email], @[Tag Number])", DBConnect);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Guest First Name]", txtBxGstFName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Guest Last Name]", txtBxGstLName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Room Number]", txtBxRm.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Departure Date]", txtBxDDate.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Return Date]", txtBxRDate.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Vehicle Colour]", txtBxVColour.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Vehicle Make]", txtBxVMake.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Plate Number]", txtBxPlate.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact First Name]", txtBxContactFName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact Last Name]", txtBxContactLName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact Number]", txtBxPhone.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Contact Email]", txtBxEmail.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Tag Number]", txtBxTag.Text);

        // don't forget to execute the query!
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Guest Information Saved Successfully");
        txtBxGstFName.Text = "";
        txtBxGstLName.Text = "";
        txtBxRm.Text = "";
        txtBxDDate.Text = "";
        txtBxRDate.Text = "";
        txtBxVColour.Text = "";
        txtBxVMake.Text = "";
        txtBxPlate.Text = "";
        txtBxContactFName.Text = "";
        txtBxContactLName.Text = "";
        txtBxPhone.Text = "";
        txtBxEmail.Text = "";
        txtBxTag.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: The command should probably be disposed too, either explicitly or by using `using(..){}`